# [OCMock][OCMProtocolMock][OCMStub]When I OCMProtocolMock a protocol(This protocol has a method),How can I invoke the real implementation of the method

Tags: ios, ocmock

code show as below：

```
- (void)test_method {
    id mockDelegate = OCMProtocolMock(@protocol(adDelegate));
    OCMExpect([mockDelegate adLoaded:OCMOCK_ANY error:OCMOCK_ANY]);
    self.delegate = mockDelegate;
    if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(adLoaded:error:)]) {
         [self.delegate adLoaded:array error:nil];
    }
    OCMVerifyAllWithDelay(mockDelegate, 15);
}

// adDelegate callback method
- (void)adLoaded:array:(NSArray*)array error:(NSError *)error {
    ......
    ......
}
```

Because I let：self.delegate = mockDelegate,So this method cannot be invoked.

How can I invoke the real implementation of the method?

### Update February 10th：

I use：

```
 OCMStub([mockDelegate adLoaded:OCMOCK_ANY error:OCMOCK_ANY])
      .andDo(^BOOL(id<adDelegate> localSelf, NSArray *array, NSError *error) {
        *error = [NSError errorWithDomain:@"Error" code:0 userInfo:nil];
        return NO;
      });
```

There is an error：

```
Incompatible block pointer types passing 'BOOL (^)(__strong id<adDelegate>, NSArray *__strong, NSError *__strong)' to parameter of type 'void (^__strong)(NSInvocation *__strong)'
```

Please advise how to solve？

### Update in a few hours

I found the answer, so this can be achieved：

```
[OCMExpect([adDelegate adLoaded:OCMOCK_ANY error:OCMOCK_ANY]) andDo:^(NSInvocation *invocation) {
        __unsafe_unretained NSArray *objects = nil;
        [invocation getArgument:&objects atIndex:2];
        
        __unsafe_unretained NSError *error = nil;
        [invocation getArgument:&error atIndex:3];
        
        [self adLoaded:objects error:error];
    }];
```

In this way, the implementation can obtain the parameters passed in when the delegate callback is triggered，and then pass the parameters in the unit test class and manually call the delegate callback.

Comment: You were getting your error because you didn't patch in https://github.com/erikdoe/ocmock/pull/470 which adds the new features for andDo:

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use an `OCMExpect().andDo()`. Note that using andDo with OCMock in its current state is a little tricky with regards to getting the memory management right. See https://github.com/erikdoe/ocmock/pull/470 for details.

Probably something like:

```
OCMExpect([mockDelegate adLoaded:OCMOCK_ANY error:OCMOCK_ANY])
.andDo(^(NSInvocation *invocation) {
        __unsafe_unretained NSArray *array = nil;
        __unsafe_unretained NSError *error = nil;
        [invocation getArgument:&array atIndex:2];
        [invocation getArgument:&error atIndex:3];
        [self adLoaded:array error:error];
      });
```

or if you patch in pull 470:

```
OCMExpect([mockDelegate adLoaded:OCMOCK_ANY error:OCMOCK_ANY])
.andDo(^void(id<adDelegate> localSelf, NSArray *array, NSError *error) {
  [self adLoaded:array error:error];
});
```

Comment: It seems that the second method is more convenient to use.I didn't know before that the parameters of the andDo function can be expanded.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Looks like pull 470 needs to be updated. I'll try and find some time. Feel free to upvote the answer :)

Comment: ok thanks. I would also like to upvote your answer,but I don't have enough reputation to upvote==